# Driving a internal wire in my module from my interface task

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm

**EDIT:** I tried out the methods mentioned below: I set my interface to wires instead of logic, and I drive 'Z from the driver that wants to relinquish control of the signal so that the other driver can take over. Still doesn't work as I see u_slave_dut not being driven from my interface. Any clues on what is wrong? My working example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4SSP

I am writing a testbench for a top-level module that has a number of sub-modules. I want to instantiate an interface and hook it up to one of my sub-modules, say **my_submodule**. Easy enough, and I can see my interface pins toggling when **my_submodule** pins are toggled. This makes for great observation.

Next, I decided I wanted to be able to toggle the pins myself from my interface (using a task). I realize this leads to 2 drivers on the same bus. So, is there a way for me to do this?

I created a small example of edaplayground to experiment, and here I see that none of my writes from my task in the interface actually toggle the pins on u_slave_dut. Also, I get no warnings from the compiler which bothers me too.

My working example is here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5fcP

**testbench.sv**

```
`include "my_interface.sv"

module tb;

  bit clk = 1'b1;
  bit control = 1'b0;

  initial begin
    forever begin
      #5 clk = ~clk;
    end
  end

  my_interface my_vif(clk);

  assign my_vif.addr   = (control)? tb.u_top.u_slave_dut.i_addr  : 'hz;
  assign my_vif.wdata  = (control)? tb.u_top.u_slave_dut.i_wdata : 'hz;
  assign my_vif.write  = (control)? tb.u_top.u_slave_dut.i_write : 'hz;

  top u_top(.clk(clk));

  initial begin
    #80  my_vif.master_write_something;
    #160 $finish;
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0);
  end
endmodule
```

**interface.sv**

```
interface my_interface(input clk);
  logic [3:0] addr;
  logic       write;
  logic [3:0] wdata;
  logic [3:0] rdata;
  logic       resp;

  clocking master_cb @(posedge clk);
    input resp, rdata;
    output addr, write, wdata;
  endclocking

  clocking slave_cb @(posedge clk);
    input addr, write, wdata;
    output resp, rdata;
  endclocking

  task master_write_something;
    @(master_cb);
    master_cb.write <= 1'b1;
    @(master_cb);
    master_cb.wdata <= 3'b101;
    master_cb.addr  <= 3'b111;
    @(master_cb);
    master_cb.write <= 1'b0;
  endtask

  task slave_write_something;
    @(slave_cb);
    slave_cb.resp <= 1'b1;
    @(slave_cb);
    slave_cb.rdata <= 3'b101;
    @(slave_cb);
    slave_cb.resp <= 1'b0;
    slave_cb.rdata <= 3'b000;
  endtask

endinterface
```

**design.sv**

```
module slave_dut (
  input clk,
  input [3:0]  i_addr,
  input [3:0]  i_wdata,
  input        i_write,
  output       o_resp,
  output [3:0] o_rdata
);

  reg       o_resp_reg;
  reg [3:0] o_rdata_reg;

  initial begin
    o_resp_reg  <= 1'b0;
    o_rdata_reg <= 'h0;
  end

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (i_write == 1'b1) begin
      o_resp_reg <= 1'b1;
      o_rdata_reg <= i_wdata;
    end
    else begin
      o_resp_reg <= 1'b0;
      o_rdata_reg <= 'h0;
    end
  end

  assign o_resp = o_resp_reg;
  assign o_rdata = o_rdata_reg;

endmodule : slave_dut

module master_dut (
  input clk,
  output [3:0] o_addr,
  output [3:0] o_wdata,
  output       o_write,
  input        i_resp,
  input  [3:0] i_rdata
);

  reg [3:0] o_addr_reg;
  reg [3:0] o_wdata_reg;
  reg       o_write_reg;

  initial begin
    o_addr_reg <= 'h0;
    o_wdata_reg <= 'h0;
    o_write_reg <= 'h0;
    repeat (2) @(posedge clk);
    o_addr_reg <= 'hF;
    o_wdata_reg <= 'hB;
    o_write_reg <= 1'b1;
    @(posedge clk);
    o_addr_reg <= 'h0;
    o_wdata_reg <= 'h0;
    o_write_reg <= 'h0;
    repeat (2) @(posedge clk);
    o_addr_reg <= 'h4;
    o_wdata_reg <= 'hD;
    o_write_reg <= 1'b1;
    @(posedge clk);
    o_addr_reg <= 'h0;
    o_wdata_reg <= 'h0;
    o_write_reg <= 'h0;
  end

  assign o_addr = o_addr_reg;
  assign o_wdata = o_wdata_reg;
  assign o_write = o_write_reg;

endmodule : master_dut

module top(input clk);
  wire [3:0] addr;
  wire [3:0] wdata;
  wire       write;
  wire       resp;
  wire [3:0] rdata;

  master_dut u_master_dut (
    .clk(clk),
    .o_addr(addr),
    .o_wdata(wdata),
    .o_write(write),
    .i_resp(resp),
    .i_rdata(rdata)
  );

  slave_dut u_slave_dut (
    .clk(clk),
    .i_addr(addr),
    .i_wdata(wdata),
    .i_write(write),
    .o_resp(resp),
    .o_rdata(rdata)   
  );

endmodule
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the one simulator you chose to run the simulator on does not give any warnings or errors. Any other simulator will correctly give the errors about mixing continuous assignments with procedural assignments from the clocking block.

If you are going to have the same signal driven from two different places, you need to deal with that by using a wire instead of a variable. You also need to turn off one of the drivers by setting it to high-impedance  (`'z`), so the other driver can control the signal. This needs to be done regardless of whether the two drivers are within your design or between the design and testbench. I wrote a [DVCon paper](http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf) a few years ago that explains this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read the paper and tried to implement what I understood: (1) I changed my interface to wires instead of logic. (2) I drove the signals to 'hZ in u_master_dut. I still don't seem to be able to drive the inputs of u_slave_dut from my_interface. What am I missing here? I also have 2 other questions: (3) I am using a procedural assignment to drive a wire in my interface. How is this allowed? (4) I will not have access to the internal driver from within top to set it to 'hZ as I have done in my example in u_master_dut. https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Y6x

Comment: (2)I would need to see the updated code to know what you missed. (3) you are making clocking block drives to the wire, not procedural assignments. check my paper and LRM (4) you may need to use `force/release`

Comment: I decided to go with signal_spy and use force/release. I wasn't able to get past the (suppresible) error that I was driving a net from 2 different drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave explained, it is the only way to control the multi driver nets by enabling only one driver to drive the net at a time. And from hardware point of view as well, only one driver should drive any wire at a time.

This can be achieved in your design by using additional `reg`.

Please refer the following code.

```
module tb;

  bit clk = 1'b1;
  reg control = 1'b1;

  initial begin
    forever begin
      #5 clk = ~clk;
    end
  end

  my_interface my_vif(clk);

  assign my_vif.addr   = (control)? tb.u_top.u_slave_dut.i_addr  : 'hz;
  assign my_vif.wdata  = (control)? tb.u_top.u_slave_dut.i_wdata : 'hz;
  assign my_vif.write  = (control)? tb.u_top.u_slave_dut.i_write : 'hz;

  top u_top(.clk(clk));

  initial begin
    #80  my_vif.master_write_something (control);
    #160 $finish;
  end

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0);
  end


endmodule

// Interface Task     
task master_write_something (ref reg x);
  @(master_cb);
  x = 1'b0;
  master_cb.write <= 1'b1;
  @(master_cb);
  master_cb.wdata <= 3'b101;
  master_cb.addr  <= 3'b111;
  @(master_cb);
  master_cb.write <= 1'b0;
endtask
```

And the dump file is as follow.

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said and it didn't work.. Please check my edit above and the working example.

Comment: Initialise `control` with `1'b1` (in your example, it is initialised with `1'b0`). In this case you'll have one Z state, in the wave, because control = 1'b0 and the task waits for `@(master_cb) signal (you can manage the control signal from that task). But apart from that it works

Comment: Initializing `control = 1'b0` sets the interface signals to 'hZ initially. Then, when I want to drive from the interface, I set `control = 1'b1` and call `master_write_something`. Either way, I tried the method of setting `control=1'b1` as well and it doesn't work... Are you running my example? Can you show me a wave if possible please?

Comment: the waveform image you showed me actually shows that this doesn't work. As you can see, driving the interface signals doesn't actually drive the input to the slave_dut. The input to the slave_dut can only be driven from the master_dut...

Comment: I can see that interface `addr`, `write`, `wdata` signals are driven with `1'bz` for few clock cycles, which is due to `tb.u_top.u_slave_dut` signals being on high impedence. Can you please point me which signals are you talking about?

Comment: I want to drive the 'wdata' 'write' and 'addr' signals of u_slave_dut from the interface task 'master_write_something'. From the waveform the interface signals are driven @time 80ns, but this does not propogate into 'u_slave_dut,'. My goal is to write into 'u_slave_dut' from both 'u_master_dut' and my interface task

Comment: That is because, in top module, you have passed only clock signal in top module. So whatever value is there in the u_slave_dut, that will be shown in interface. But interface values won't be shown to those nets. So you should first complete the connections. And now if you add those signals in top module as well, then `addr`, `write` and `wdata` will have multiple drivers - through interface, through u_master_dut. So you need to again do arrangements for that.